# 汉长安城的未央宫中的“前殿”是一幢房屋，还是几幢建筑在面积宽大的布局里？

Tags: culture, history, place-names

首先得说，我明白现代人对古代的殿、殿堂、皇宫等建筑的样子只不过是考古上的推测。那么，根据某几个词典（现代汉语规范词典、汉语大词典、萌典、两岸通用词典），一个“殿”绝对是单独的房屋；“前殿”是“正殿”，而“正殿”就是一种殿（皇宫中的主殿）。

我在网上看到的一些对未央宫的前殿的复原设想图就大不一致。且看下面的图一和图二。

图一：陕西西安汉长安未央宫遗址前殿复原设想鸟瞰图（来源：https://share.ixian.cn/wap/thread/view-thread/tid/255699)（该文章好像有一些相互矛盾的地方）

[image: Text]

图二：未央宫前殿（来源：https://wantubizhi.com/image.aspx)（从较好的角度给你看：https://img2.autoimg.cn/travelplat/g16/M02/4C/84/1185x0_1_autohomecar__wKjBx1fedzaAXMgEAAemLlwqSDU137.jpg)

[image: Text]

我觉得图一是错的，因为它看上去就是宫城，而图二是对的，这个才更像正殿呢。

所以呢，在我看来，古代未央宫的根基面积固然大约5平方千米，前殿则只不过是它墙内的相对很小的完整的一座建筑而已，请问这都是对的吗？谢谢。

EDIT: I just edited a single word (had accidentally wrote 奠基 instead of 根基)

Comment: Chinese StackExchange 是個「語言問答网站」，恐怕這種問題不適合在這裏問

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**未央宫选址總平面圖**
[image]

未央宫总面积约5平方千米，约占汉长安城面积的七分之一，较长乐宫稍小，但建筑本身的壮丽宏伟则有过之。四面建宫门各一，东门和北门有阙。东阙在东司马门外，正对长乐宫西阙。宫内有殿堂四十余屋，还有六座小山和多处水池，大小门户近百，与长乐宫之间又建有阁道相通。

**未央宫前殿**
[image]

**前殿**
秦汉时代，宫城之中的大朝正殿称“前殿”。前殿筑于龙首山的山丘之上，《西京赋》“疏龙首以抗殿，状巍峨以岌嶪”就记叙了这个情况。
未央宫前殿是未央宫的主体建筑，前殿内又分为前、中、后三大殿，其中的中殿是正殿，皇帝登基、重要朝会、皇家婚丧等大典均在此举行。

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%9C%AA%E5%A4%AE%E5%AE%AB/22415

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129066/discussion-on-answer-by-r13-).

Comment: Thanks for leading me to find and correct my misunderstanding. The ancient Chinese rich people's home was called "宅" which consisted of 前進(院), 中進(庭), 和後進(院), and may have numerous individual units/buildings within the property. Now I think 未央宫 is similar to Washington D.C. which is consisted of a collection of government buildings (殿), and each building is similar to 宅. So inside the前殿, it again separated into 前殿,前殿, 和路寝.